# How can we store data in the MUMPS format?

Tags: ibm-infosphere, ibm-information-server

This is something we would like to do (storing data in the MUMPS format in Information Server) but it seems like we are unable to store data in this format. Does anyone have guidance or a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether via 3rd party ODBC/JDBC drivers or adapters, you can use DS with/for MUMPs in my experience. I would recommend checking with their specific MUMPs vendor on the availability of ODBC/JDBC drivers. Otherwise, iWay (Information Builders) provides/supports adapters for this. Hope this helps.